Selecting rows in bigquery where given value(s) fall between two column values of the table
I have the following table1 in bigquery. Now I need generate n random values and select the rows from table 1 where the generated random values fall between table1.Low and table1.High. How can I do this in bigquery.
Table 1
|id |Value | Low  | High |
|---|------|------|------|
|1  |6.45  | 0    | 0.24 |
|2  |2.33  | 0.24 | 0.34 |
|3  |5.67  | 0.34 | 0.54 |
|4  |5.67  | 0.54 | 0.6  |
|5  |5.67  | 0.6  | 0.76 |
|6  |5.67  | 0.76 | 1    |

4 random values generated
|rand |
|-----|
|0.21 |
|0.19 |
|0.05 |
|0.85 |

Expected result:
|id |Value | Low  | High |
|---|------|------|------|
|1  |6.45  | 0    | 0.24 |
|1  |6.45  | 0    | 0.24 |
|1  |6.45  | 0    | 0.24 |
|6  |5.67  | 0.76 | 1    |


Use below
select t.*
from table_1 t
join table_2 
on rand between low and high

if applied to sample data from your questions
with table_1 as (
  select 1 id, 6.45 value, 0 low,    0.24 high union all
  select 2, 2.33, 0.24, 0.34 union all
  select 3, 5.67, 0.34, 0.54 union all
  select 4, 5.67, 0.54, 0.6 union all
  select 5, 5.67, 0.6,  0.76 union all
  select 6, 5.67, 0.76, 1 
), table_2 as (
  select 0.21 rand union all
  select 0.19 union all
  select 0.05 union all
  select 0.85 
)

output is


This will work, but you really should be aware of which values you are evaluating against, so I have included this in a column.
WITH
  table1 AS (
    SELECT 1 as id, 6.45 as Value, 0 as low, 0.24 as high
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 as id, 6.45 as Value, 0 as low, 0.24 as high
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 as id, 2.33 as Value, 0.24 as low, 0.34 as high
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 as id, 5.67 as Value, 0.34 as low, 0.54 as high
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 as id, 5.67 as Value, 0.54 as low, 0.6 as high
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 as id, 5.67 as Value, 0.6 as low, 0.76 as high
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 as id, 5.67 as Value, 0.76 as low, 1 as high
  ),

  table2 AS (
    SELECT
      ROUND(RAND(),2) AS rand
    FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1,4))
  )

SELECT
  table1.*, table2.rand
FROM table1
  INNER JOIN table2
ON 
  table2.rand BETWEEN table1.low AND table1.high

Since BETWEEN evaluates as >= low and <= high, be aware that a number on a boundary will evaluate twice, e.g. 0.76 will match to both ids 5 and 6.
If you use table2.rand > table1.low AND table2.rand <= table1.high then 0 will never be matched.
Similarly, if you use table2.rand >= table1.low AND table2.rand < table1.high then 1 will never be matched.
